# Python - how to open excel sheets at a particular time each day

Tags: python, excel, workflow

In my job we run 10 or so reports a day and I have a bad habit of forgetting them until a few minutes before the deadline. I want to make a python program that will run in the background that will automatically open a particular excel program when I need to start looking at it.

I'm sure I'm not the first one to think of this, has anyone seen something like this before? I'm really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction. I've searched stackoverflow, github and lots of google searches, with no luck.

Comment: write the script, schedule in on OS, in Windows with Task Scheduler, On Linux with CronTab, ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a kinda new to python and probably not able to write it all myself. I'll look into Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not even need python to do this task, a bash script or batch file is more that sufficient, you can even write your command in scheduler

But as you requested this is the python code you can run excel and open your file:

```
from subprocess import call
call(r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\excel.exe D:\Documents\Servers.xlsx')
```

This code opens Servers.xlsx from my Documents folder on D: drive
Beware of `r` before string passed into call function, if not provided you should use \\ instead of \